# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` on rendering with Trinidad 1.0.12 on JSF 1.2. Some pages are working fine but on some pages I am getting this error. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
Thanks

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager(RootRenderingContext.java:193)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UIXComponentUINode.getRenderer(UIXComponentUINode.java:379)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UIXComponentUINode.renderInternal(UIXComponentUINode.java:166)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UINodeRendererBase.encodeEnd(UINodeRendererBase.java:70)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:693)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:70)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.RenderUtils.encodeRecursive(RenderUtils.java:65)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:299)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:321)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.PanelPartialRootRenderer.renderContent(PanelPartialRootRenderer.java:64)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.BodyRenderer.renderContent(BodyRenderer.java:142)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.PanelPartialRootRenderer.encodeAll(PanelPartialRootRenderer.java:119)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.BodyRenderer.encodeAll(BodyRenderer.java:78)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:224)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:693)
  at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:252)
  at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:249)
  at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.encodeRecursive(ComponentSupport.java:249)
  at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:182)
  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
```

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager According to the 1st hit it's already reported and currently still unresolved.

Comment: yes, last couple of weeks I am facing that issue... Is there any artifact id change or jar problem??

Comment: Looks to be a Windows / IE issue. For reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2451